# Is it possible to write a aggregation query in Dev Tools of Kibana and then store the result?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a field in elastic search loaded that has information in it as:
message: Requesting 30 containers
message: Requesting 40 containers
.
.
.
message: Requesting 50 containers

I want to get a total of all containers used in the job. (30+40+50=120, in this case). 
Is it more efficient to extract these values in a field in logstash and then use aggregation queries in elasticsearch or given the message above everything is possible in elasticsearch?
Also, if I write a aggregation query in Dev Tools of Kibana, then is it possible to store the result to be used for visualization?

Answer (score 0):

- It is better and is the solution to extract the number in logstash and then use it in aggregations
- No , You cant use a string in sum aggregation , Everything is never possible
- You dont need you write aggregation query in dev tools if you are using kibana , in kibana you can do aggregations without writing queries